# How to pass an object to select box

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a list of products displayed in a select box. I'm getting the product list from request. The product object has few fields like `code`, `name`, `description`, etc.

On select box, I'm displaying the product name and I want a whole product object to be sent to the action upon selection on form submission?

Comment: <s:hidden/> or session

Comment: How session will help? Using hidden variable, is there anyway we can do without JavaScript?

Comment: `How session will help?` You store the entire object in session, send it to the page, return only the id and the modified data, then merge the object from the session with the new data serverside. `Using hidden variable, is there anyway we can do without JavaScript?` No javascript involved, just use a form

Comment: Can you elaborate how to use hidden in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using select box it stores the value of the option which is selected. Object properties should be bound to other input controls of the form when you submit it to the action.

> Struts2 uses params interceptor to populate form values submitted by
>   HTTP request.
>
> It's recommended to use POST method, so if you have sensitive data and
>   you want it is not reflected in the URL.
>
> Parameter names are used by the interceptor to pass through OGNL
>   runtime to evaluate the expression which should find reference in the
>   valueStack.